# Parse SharedPreferences String

Tags: android, parsing, sharedpreferences, textview

I have an idea that would require me to save a long string message into SharedPreferences. I would then have to pull one word at a time from this message and throw it onto a TextView, one by one until the message is completed. Does this sound possible to anyone? If so, can someone give me a hint as to how to implement something like this? Thanks!

Comment: Read the message.  Split the string around spaces using the split function.  Set up a timer, when the timer goes off add the next word to the text of the TextView (keep a counter so you know what the next word is).  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Sounds like what I've envisioned. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving into shared preferences is like this:

```
    final SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    final Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString(PreferencesUtils.NAME, name);
    editor.commit();
```

Reading from them, like this:

```
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString(preference, null);
```

Other than that, Gabe's comment seems good to me with a small tweak. I would use a broadcast pending intent to trigger the updates.